# Wind scaling in Maxscript

Tags: max, maxscript, 3ds

I'm trying to write a script in 3ds max, which creates smoke animation. I recorded the process of creating the scene and I have a problem to recreate it by script. I want to set wind parameters:

```
select $'Smoke wind'
$.frequency = 0.78
$.turbulence = 0.03
$.scale = 0.03 -- problem
```

But I received the following error:

```
Unable to convert: 0.03 to type: Point3
```

And I have no idea what could go wrong, because when I set parameters in 3ds max, everything's ok. The problem occurs only when I type scale instruction in console. Anyone knows what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also the object-level scale property for the scale of an object (X,Y,Z), which is the reason for this ambiguity and error. Access the Wind baseObject instead, like this:

```
$.baseObject.scale = 0.03
```